# Культура и искусство

Tags: значение-слов

Я понимаю, что культура и искусство - это не одно и то же. Но вот, когда, например, пишешь список тем, то, если написал "культура", надо ли писать и "искусство" (а ведь эти слова мы постоянно видим рядом)? Ведь искусство, как я понимаю, это и так часть культуры. Почему же их всегда пишут вместе, будто противопоставляя?

Comment: И культура, и искусство — слова очень многозначные, могут пониматься то шире, то уже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Культура в историческом смысле - знание, выраженное в материальной и духовной форме, накопленное человечеством в истории до данного момента. Также применимо к отдельным категориям населения страны: Испанская культура, части света: Европейская к., времени: Античная к.

Культура в бытовом значении - союлюдение норм поведения, одобряемых данным обществом.

Искусство - любая и каждая область человеческой деятельности, где результат требует высшего мастерства от исполнителя.

Во фразе культура и искусство России 19 в. Я говорю о предметах, сохранившихся и известных из документов, о нормах поведения и их причинах, о духовных ценностях общества этого периода. А также о высших достижениях человеческих рук и ума.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, культура и искусство очень часто оказываются рядом, например:

До XVIII века культура и искусство Западной Европы и Древней Руси живут своей жизнью, развиваются по своим законам.

Новое мировоззрение ― это новая культура и искусство.

Мир третьего тысячелетия (человек и общество, наука и техника, градостроительство и транспорт, культура и искусство будущего).

Эта пролетарская культура и искусство.

Наука, культура и искусство ценились им единственно ради их практической пользы.

Культура и искусство достигают в наши дни невиданно пышного расцвета.

Нет сомнения, что искусство - это часть культуры. Сочетание "культура и искусство" больше похоже на штамп, устойчивое выражение. Его смысл - культура и искусство как ее отдельная часть, связанная с художественным творчеством человека.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, не противопоставляя, а ставя в один ряд. И не так уж часто их пишут рядом.

Answer (score 0):

...надо ли писать и "искусство". Нет, не надо, если разговор пойдёт о культуре пития, например.